# Why outbox emails is always an empty array in microsoft graph api?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to read my email from Outbox folder.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/outbox/messages

I'm using mail flow rules to defear the delivery of the messages by 1 minutes, so the email is going to outbox for almost 1 minute before sending the message

The problem is I'm getting an empty array everytime I query for the outbox folder

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('3bab4ea2-2100-4265-9dee-6aac1adc666a')/mailFolders('outbox')/messages",
    "value": []
}
```

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you send the email eg if you send from Outlook and the client is in Cache Mode then when you use delayed delivery the Message is stored in the Outbox in the OST Cache and not synced to the server so wouldn't be available online (and in the Graph). You might want to test it using OWA instead but with OWA it saves deferred delivery messages to the drafts folder not the Outbox.

Comment: yeah, I just tested without the cache mode and I do get the messages in the graph api from the outbox, but the outlook client is too slow without cache mode, and the message doesn't even send after the delay time, stay in the outbox forever

Comment: have you considered using the OnSend feature in an Outlook-Addin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

Comment: yeah, we already have a solution with that, but too slow for what we need